# How to convert a date string with both Etc/GMT into Python date time?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Apple is returning a strange format for the expiration date of a receipt:

> 2018-06-18 15:03:55 Etc/GMT

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('2018-06-18 15:03:55 Etc/GMT', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Etc and GMT are both the same.

I have tried to convert it like this into a datetime object, but failed doing so.

```
ValueError: time data '2018-06-18 15:03:55 Etc/GMT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Why are there two time zones defined in the first place? And how can I make Python understanding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [Etc/GMT appears to be a valid, existing time zone](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?s=default&tz=Etc/GMT), just datetime does not seem to recognize it. You can do the following if you have the possibility to install [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt, tz = '2018-06-18 15:03:55 Etc/GMT'.rsplit(maxsplit=1) # rsplit() for simplicity, obviously re would make this safer

dto = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tz))
print(dto) # result: 2018-06-18 15:03:55+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct approach..but if it helps.

```
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = '2018-06-18 15:03:55 Etc/GMT'
print( parse(re.sub("(?<=:\d{2}\s).*\/", r"", s)) )
```

**Output:**

```
2018-06-18 15:03:55+00:00
```

- I am using regex to remove `Etc/` from the src datetime
- Using `dateutil` to convert to datetime object.

Comment: No, I would need it, otherwise the date is wrong without the timezone.